# Как поменять фон 2 тэгов div с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html, background, swap

```
if(big.style.backgroundImage=img1.style.backgroundImage) {
  big.style.backgroundImage=img2.style.backgroundImage
}
```

Пробовал так

Comment: вам нужно сразу найти эти теги через js к примеру с помощью querySelector и потом уже менять их

Comment: `if (... == ...) { ... }` не жалейте пробелов в коде - легче будет заметить такие ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задавать цвет каким либо классом и проверять существует ли класс, вместо того, чтобы проверять какой цвет у елемента. Например, у вас есть елемент `div` c `background-color: green` заданный классом `.changeColor`. Скрипт проверяет существование класса, и если он присвоен елементу, то `background-color` изменится на `#fff`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var your_color = '#fff';
  var selector = $('#big');
  if(selector.hasClass('changeColor')) {
    selector.css('background-color',your_color);
  }
});
```

```css
#big {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.changeColor {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="big" class="changeColor">My text</div>
```